# how to install catboost-0.14.2-cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl wheel file on Mac Terminal?

Tags: python

I am trying to install "catboost-0.14.2-cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl" wheel file on Mac Terminal.
But getting the following error:

> catboost-0.14.2-cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I am basically trying to invoke a catboost module verion 0.14.2, which is apparently not available anymore.

Does anybody have an idea how to install wheel file?

Comment: As you can see from the filename, it is a Linux wheel. You are going to need a version for MacOS.

Comment: Thanks Klaus D.
As per your suggestion I am trying to search for a MacOS wheel. But cannot find one. Instead I found this, do you think this will help? https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/2f35e0366c0bb6c1b44be89fda0a02fe12f84513/catboost/python-package/catboost/eval/catboost_evaluation.py#L30